# How to pass a bytestring to PyGreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, formatting

I've got a PostgreSQL table with a column of type `bytea`. Porting that table from SQLite, I ran into an issue - I couldn't figure out how to pass raw binary data to an SQL query. The framework I use is PyGreSQL. I want to stick to the DB-API 2.0 interface to avoid a lot of conversion.
That interface, unlike the classic one (dollar-sign parameters) and SQLite (question-mark parameters), requires to specify the type (%-formatting like the old Python's).
The data I want to pass is a PNG file, binary-read using the `'rb'` flag in the `open()` method.
The query code looks like this:

```
db = pgdb.connect(args)
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (%b)', (b'test_bytes',))
```

This gives an error `unsupported format character 'b' (0x62) at index 54` and doesn't allow the formatting to happen. What could be done to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a solution, but a good-enough workaround. I decided to use `psycopg2` instead of `PyGreSQL` as it is more supported and common, so it's easier to find info about any common problems.
There, the solution would be to use `%s` for every type, which I find much more Pythonic (no need to think about types in a dynamically-typed language)

So, my query would look like this:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (%s)', (b'test_bytes',))
```